# DNS records for subdomains and IIS bindings

Tags: iis, dns, subdomain, mx-record

We have some donamin somedomain.com
It already has DNS A record that binds somedomain.com to some IP: XX.XX.XX.62

Now we need to add couple subdomains that will look like sub1.somedomain.com, sub2.somedomain.com that will point to other IP say XX.XX.XX.65 and will lead to corresponding sites within IIS.

What kind of records should be added to DNS and are any special adjustments on IIS site binding needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy:

```
sub1.somedomain.com A 300 XX.XX.XX.65 - In IIS binding hostname shoud look same sub1.somedomain.com
sub2.somedomain.com A 300 XX.XX.XX.65 - In IIS binding hostname shoud look same sub2.somedomain.com
```

That's it.